# What happens at install time for Content Security Policy (CSP) Trusted Sites included in a package?

Tags: managed-package, package-install, csp, content-security-policy

When Remote Site Settings are packaged, for manual installs there is a prompt at install time to confirm the add of those settings to the org.

Looks like [Content Security Policy (CSP) Trusted Sites are packageable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_csptrustedsite); **what happens at install time for those?**

(Related information but not a direct answer here
[SFDX installing a managed package not deploying CSP trusted sites or remote site settings](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261664/sfdx-installing-a-managed-package-not-deploying-csp-trusted-sites-or-remote-site)).

**PS**

Adding the text Rohit mentioned as I missed that when I first looked at the documentation so want to draw attention to it here:

> When you include the CspTrustedSite component in a package, the
> permissions for the third-party APIs and Websocket connections apply
> to sites and pages across the org. Because this component modifies
> security, we don’t recommend including CspTrustedSite components in
> packages. Instead, we recommend that you instruct customers to use the
> CSP Trusted Sites Setup page or the CSPTrustedSites metadata API type
> to add the URLs to their allowlist as part of activating your package.
> If you choose to include CspTrustedSite components in your package,
> disclose this change prominently in your package documentation to
> ensure that your customers are aware of security modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_csptrustedsite) documentation covering the CSP sites for managed packages.

As per above document , it is not recommended to include `CSP Trusted sites` in managed packages.

But as a managed package developer using `CSP Trusted Sites` in our package, I can confirm that while installing, below popup appears for user consent of CSP site :

[image]